# Частота генерации RSA ключей

Tags: безопасность, rsa

Добрый день.

Стоит задача шифровать общение между сервером и Android-клиентом.
Порядок действия таковой:
1) Клиент подключается и стартует php-сессию.
2) Сервер генерирует/достаёт пару ключей, отсылает публичный ключ клиенту.
3) Клиент, в свою очередь, генерирует ещё одну пару ключей, и отсылает свой  публичный ключ серверу.
4) Дальнейшее общение осуществляется по этому защищённому каналу, посредством POST-ов и GET-ов.

**Вопрос:** как часто стоит генерировать новые ключи? Сервер и клиент могут создавать новые ключи при каждом старте сессии, но генерация ключей - операция сложная и затратная, особенно при большой нагрузке сервера. С другой стороны, хранить секретный и публичный ключи в бд и на устройстве клиента не слишком безопасно.

Буду рад любым ответам, советам и ссылкам на тему грамотного проектирования безопасных клиент-серверных систем. Прошу указать на ошибки и заблуждения в моих размышлениях, и простить за глупость и наивность.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое главное правило в криптографии - никогда не изобретайте свою систему шифрования. И вот почему.

Ваша система шифрования не имеет смысла. Если атакующий сможет перехватывать и модифицировать трафик, он создаст 2 пары ключей, назовем их фейк-сервер, и фейк-клиент. Каждый ключ отсылается соответствующей стороне.

Теперь, если сервер хочет передать зашифрованное сообщение, он шифрует его ключом фейк-клиент (ведь он получил этот ключ от атакующего и думает, что это ключ клиента). Атакующий расшифровывает сообщение, и шифрует настоящим ключом клиента, и уже пересылает клиенту. Аналогично и в другую сторону, если клиент хочет отправить сообщение серверу.

Получается, атакующий может полностью прослушивать канал связи и даже изменять сообщения.

Все эти проблемы уже решены в `TLS`, и вы можете использовать просто передачу информации через `https`.