# На какой стороне, клиента или сервера, генерируются ключи шифрования RSA и как происходит их последующий обмен?

Tags: безопасность, клиент-сервер, криптография, rsa

Интересует следующий вопрос касательно алгоритма RSA: в момент подключения клиента к серверу, как и где происходит генерация ключей и последующий обмен ключами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете ввиду шифрование RSA (не путать с подписью RSA), то генерирует ключи тот, кто будет делать расшифровку. Это может быть как клиент, так и сервер, зависит уже от конкретного протокола.

Первая сторона, которая генерирует ключи, отправляет публичный ключ второй стороне, вторая сторона шифрует что-то этим ключом, и отправляет шифротекст обратно, и первая сторона производит расшифровку приватным ключом.

Comment: скажем сервер и клиент общаются в обе стороны, получается у каждой должны быть публичный и приватный ключи, правильно? а генерируются где эти самые ключи? у каждого на своей стороне? а потом идет обмен своими публичными ключами?

Comment: Не обязательно обеим сторонам иметь свои ключи. И вообще, нельзя использовать только RSA шифрование. Любой, кто сможет прослушивать и изменять трафик, сможет прочитать все, что вы зашифровали, даже в обе стороны.

Comment: @UserLevel0 просто используйте https, там реализовано все что нужно

Comment: @UserLevel0 задайте новые конкретные вопросы, что не понятно, или посмотрите уже существующие, я здесь на много вопросов про TLS отвечал

Comment: хорошо, буду поднимать вам репутацию:)

Comment: @UserLevel0 вот здесь объяснение, почему нельзя использовать чистый RSA https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795432/Частота-генерации-rsa-ключей/795441#795441